# Javascript regex: How to find length of a match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I got a task to write code highlighter for C#. Everything's pretty good, but I wish to optimize indentation. So, I have a regexp looking like `/(\t|[ ]{4})/g`, so I replace tabulation or 4 space chars with `<span style="margin-left: 2em;" />` and it looks good, but it creates a lot of unnecessary spans. I want to use something like `/^[ ]{x}/g` and replace with `<span style='margin-left: "+(0.5*x)+"em;' />` to have only one span per line with appropriate margin. `str.match()` won't work because it searches in all document, not per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regular expression has the `g` flag, you can execute it over and over again, getting all matches from the string, including the length of the match:

```
var re = /^(\t|[ ]{4})/g;
var match;
while((match = re.exec(text)) {
    // use match.index and match[0].length
}
```

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly well. For those who might encounter it, I replaced the patter via `str.split(0, match.index)+"<span>"+str.split(match.index+match[0].length-1)`